# Passing secret variables to Google Colaboratory notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is there a secure way for public (shared with someone) Google Colaboratory notebooks to import security sensitive variables like access tokens?

I have a notebook with code like this one:

```
TOKEN='7o6kti1TW7ebwXXG6ZAdVkS08MzDBLG00oXTCNTYEbB5A'
items = json.loads(
  requests.get('https://someservice.com/api/items?access_token={}'.format(TOKEN)).text
)
```

I want share the notebook with other users so they are able to run and edit code cells, but I want to move TOKEN variable definition to some hidden place. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code inside @Bob Smith's [linked colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bjBVx6pokBm_A1em-XdURQAmemlUAgYz)

```py
from getpass import getpass

token = getpass('Enter token here')
print ('token is', token)
```

Comment: Note to moderators: I tried to edit the original answer but there's too many queued edits. I also tried to add as a comment but the formatting put it on one line making it hard to read.

Comment: Tomiwa: volunteer moderators are on strike presently, so they are unlikely to see your message. However the review queue should still be operational - did the system actually disallow your edit?

Comment: Okay, the review queue is operational now and I've submitted an edit. If my edit gets approved, should I delete this answer? If I delete it what happens to the points I've accrued. Maybe I should just leave it for posterity.

Comment: Why would you delete it? If it might be useful to future readers, I would suggest leaving it be.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to assign the token at invocation time using `getpass`.

Here's an example:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bjBVx6pokBm_A1em-XdURQAmemlUAgYz

```py
from getpass import getpass

token = getpass('Enter token here')
print ('token is', token)
```